# how to combine a single secret value from Azure KeyVault and aggregating it with other values in appSettings file and send as IConfiguration

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault

In below code `app.UseElasticApm` requires IConfiguration which I wants to read from both appsettings file and Azure Keyvault. Here `ElasticApm--SecretToken` I wants to read from Azure KeyVault.

**appSettings**

```
"ElasticApm": {
//"SecretToken": null,
"ServiceName": "Sample-1 ElasticApm",
"CaptureBody": "all",
"LogLevel": "Debug"
```

},

**Program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        builder.Services.AddControllers();
        var app = builder.Build();

        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri("keyvault-url"), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var secretVal = client.GetSecret("ElasticApm--SecretToken").Value;

        app.UseElasticApm(builder.Configuration);

        app.MapControllers();

        app.Run();
    }
```

These 2 lines of code gives me the secrets value from Azure KeyVault, but question is how to  combine with other appSettings file and send as a IConfiguration?

I have below workaround, but it's fetching all the secret's to memory, etc.

```
var keyVaultEndpoint = new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyStoreUrl") ?? string.Empty);
        builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(keyVaultEndpoint,
            new DefaultAzureCredential());
        app.UseAllElasticApm(builder.Configuration);
```

Comment: you could always implement a `KeyVaultSecretManager` to filter out the secrets: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0#use-a-key-name-prefix

Comment: thanks. true, I can do that, but I need without this.

Comment: So in your first approach, the easiest is probably to add the `ElasticApm--SecretToken` value as env variable after you retrieved it.

Comment: Thanks. how to set as environment variable after fetch from keyvault? Will it automatically resolve for `builder.Configuration`?

Comment: @user584018 I have addressed the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76311041/how-to-fetch-value-from-azure-keyvault-and-set-as-environment-variable-along-wit) which you have posted on 23rd May.Check once and let us know.