# How to fetch value from Azure KeyVault and set as environment variable along with other appSettings values

Tags: environment-variables, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, azure-keyvault

In below code, I am trying to fetch the secrets from Azure KeyVault and then sets as environment variable and reason for this is that I don't want to read it from `appsettings.json` file.

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        
        var app = builder.RegisterServices().Build();

        var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyStoreUrl") ?? string.Empty), new DefaultAzureCredential());
        var url = client.GetSecret("APM--Url").Value.Value;
        var token = client.GetSecret("APM--Token").Value.Value;

        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APM--Url", url);
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APM--Token", token);

        builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "APM");
        
        app.UseAllElasticApm(builder.Configuration);

        app.Run();
    }
```

Secrets are coming from Keyvault without any issue but further while calling `app.UseAllElasticApm(builder.Configuration);` it's not set's the values correctly.

What is missing here?

Please note some variables value (ServiceName) I want to read from appSettings file and some (Url, Token) I want to retrieve from Azure Keyvault and combined value I want to send as `builder.Configuration`.

```
"APM": {
"Url": "XXXXXXXXX",
"Token": "XXXXXX",
"ServiceName": "Sample"
```

},

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> reason for this is that I don't want to read it from `appsettings.json` file.

If you don't want to read it from `appsettings.json` file, we can set the values in the `Application settings` in `Configuration` section of the deployed App or in the Environment Variables.

The values set in the Application Settings will be then available in the Environment Variables with the prefix `Application_KeyName`.

> (Url, Token) I want to retrieve from Azure Keyvault

- Add the secrets in Key Vault.

[image]

In My `Program.cs` I have used the same code which you are using to retrieve values from `Key Vault` .

> ````cs
> var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyStoreUrl") ?? string.Empty), new DefaultAzureCredential()); 
> var url = client.GetSecret("Url").Value.Value; 
> var token = client.GetSecret("Token").Value.Value; ```
> ````

- `Url` and `Token` Values from Key Vault.

[image]

[image]

My Initial local Environment Variables.

[image]

Now set the secret values (URL and Token) which we retrieved from Key Vault and ServiceName from `appsettings.json` , to Environment Variables.

```cs
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Url", url);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Token", token);
```

My Complete code from `Program.cs` file :

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("KeyStoreUrl") ?? string.Empty), new DefaultAzureCredential());
var url = client.GetSecret("Url").Value.Value;
var token = client.GetSecret("Token").Value.Value;

var ServiceName = builder.Configuration["ServiceName"];

Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APM--Url", url);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APM--Token", token);
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("APM--ServiceName", ServiceName);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

var myconfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true)
        .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "APM")
        .Build();

var APMUrl = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APM--Url");
var APMToken = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APM--Token");
var APMServiceName= Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APM--ServiceName");

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

Now Iam able to retrieve the values using `GetEnvironmentVariable`.

***Output from Environment Variables:***

[image]

[image]

[image]